# HTTP headers for the most permanent caching possible

Tags: http, caching, header

For example: a stable release of jQuery will never change until the next version. When that happens, the URL will change.

Also, images like a website logo can be cached and when it changes I simply change the URL that is used to call it.

The header I know of is

```
Expires: Tue, 01 Feb 2050 00:00:00 GMT
```

I believe there are one or more additional headers I can use to add to the caching for proxies and maybe there is something I don't know about.

**Are there any other headers I should know about?**

Granted the cache will get deleted beyond my control. But I want to cache as much as possible.

Also this does not cover CSS/JavaScript minify/compile and it also does not count image compression or content compression such as gzip.

Comment: Could you outline your question?

Comment: Sorry, Is this better? @Gumbo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Expires* is HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 introduced the more versatile [*Cache-Control*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) where you can not just specify an expiration date but also cacheability and revalidation.

I recommend you to read [Mark Nottingham’s *Caching Tutorial*](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: I am sorry, but I would really rather not read 12 pages about caching. I would prefer just to know what the headers should be to say that I am perfectly happy with permanent caching for this URL and I don't care if it gets out or is left hanging.

Comment: @George Bailey: Understanding *Cache-Control* is actually tricky, indeed. But if you want that your resource is cacheable by any cache without any restrictions, use `Cache-Control: public, max-age=315360000`. *public* means that the resource may be cached by any cache (including public caches) even though the response may not be cacheable due to some restrictions. And although *max-age* is only 10 years, an expiry date of more than one year in the future is considered to never expire.